# Errors while implementing Braintree SDK in iOS app (swift 2.2 / xcode 7.3)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, braintree

While Stripe integration was very simple, the Braintree integration is not working for me:

I am using the Braintree guide (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) and implementing the SDK in an App designed for iOS 9.2 with Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2.

1. I successfully installed the Braintree pod
2. I've added the *use_frameworks!* statement in my pod file
3. I've added *import Braintree* into my ViewController

... and then everything goes wrong when I try the simulator:

(1)

```
*error: /Users/Rob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-  anaajuuxtxcuorcukyrbchlrbqed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Braintree/Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle: No such file or directory
```

(2)

```
error: /Users/Rob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-anaajuuxtxcuorcukyrbchlrbqed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Braintree/Braintree-UI-Localization.bundle: No such file or directory
```

(3)

```
No such module 'Braintree'*
```

*Edit: I fixed (3) by adding a Bridge header (although I assumed based on the guide that you won't need one if you use use_frameworks!)*

I see an additional error in Build phases:

```
*diff "${PODS_ROOT}/../Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    cat << EOM
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
EOM
    exit 1
fi*
```

(I updated CocoaPods and did the 'pod install', but its not working)

Any help?

Best,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue with CocoaPods 1.0.0 beta 6, based on [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5034). I was able to work around this issue by reverting to 1.0.0 beta 5. Can you let me know if that fixes the issue?